# GnuPG outputting rubbish when trying to use the encrypt option

Tags: linux, encryption, gnupg, public-key-encryption, gpg-agent

I've been using GnuPG fine for the past year or so, but I haven't encrypted anything directly from the CLI for a while. I've been trying to do it today and this is the weird output I get. Doesn't matter how trusted the key is and any input you add after the crud doesn't do anything.

```
robotmay@Computer ~> gpg --encrypt --recipient "somebloke@something.com"                                                                        09:31:19
gpg: checking the trustdb
gpg: marginals needed: 3  completes needed: 1  trust model: PGP
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   3  signed:   1  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 3u
gpg: depth: 1  valid:   1  signed:   0  trust: 1-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 0u
gpg: next trustdb check due at 2018-01-11
�
 ��|C��<2t�l�c
!%B�~ͼS�C�C��1%f��0�H�����1Ht�6����H3�
                                      Y��
�K*\�����,�i=                            )c
             �*E
$)yN%Pz.f       ����l}@ t����$3AڇU���/z�
                                        ��:VY���,�@I4w7����C���R�:T�0�r�
ϐL��"�
```

I've tried encrypting stuff via Keybase' GnuPG integration, too; but that just seems to hang indefinitely (probably because of this sort of output). Last time I used anything GnuPG it was probably 2-3 weeks ago via Enigmail and that worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

`gpg --encrypt` without any file argument encrypts from STDIN and outputs to STDOUT. Without another `--armor`/`-a` option, GnuPG will produce a binary OpenPGP message (`--armor` will produce the well-known `-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----` or similar output).

What you see is not garbage, it's the binary representation interpreted as ASCII characters of the metadata of an encrypted OpenPGP message. By adding `| gpg --list-packets` you can pipe the contents back into (another instance of) GnuPG listing technical details of the OpenPGP message.

You either have to provide some input to encrypt (a filename as parameter or by piping input through STDIN) so that GnuPG terminates, or if you want to provide the message by typing into the command line, terminate the input by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.